# Upgrading MongoDB 3.2 to 3.6 problematic?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have an older service running against MongoDB 3.2. It's nothing very complicated, but I'd like to upgrade to the latest version of MongoDB (3.6).  Is there anything I need to do to prepare for the upgrade and is it very risky for things breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade from a version earlier than the 3.4-series, you must successively upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 3.4-series. For example, if you are running a 3.2-series, you must upgrade first to upgrade first to 3.4 before you can upgrade to 3.6.

More info in:
[enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/)